# What is the default android:sharedUserId set if android:sharedUserId was not set

Tags: android, android-manifest

From the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html#uid):

> The name of a Linux user ID that will be shared with other applications. **By default,** Android assigns each application its own unique user ID.

Say I have an app that does not specify android:sharedUserId in the AndroidManifest.xml file.

Is the default sharedUserId Android generates (see above documentation) set in the build (same for this app on all devices) or is a different sharedUserId being generated on each device the app is installed?

Answer (score 2):

Android generate random unique ID for each application you installed on your device.

You can get this value by:

```
adb shell dumpsys package com.example.myapp | grep userId=
```

or in code with :

```
int uId = getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo("com.example.myapp",PackageManager.GET_META_DATA).uid;
```

But if you set `android:sharedUserId` with the same value for two or more apps, they will all share the same ID — provided that their certificate sets are identical.

Apps with the same user ID can access each other's data and, if desired, run in the same process.